# firequery says jQuery is being called incorrectly

Tags: jquery

I installed Firequery, and now Firebug is saying that jQuery is being called incorrectly.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the `google.load()` syntax, rather than the browser's native `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>` option? Also, while Firequery may say it's being called incorrectly, it's worth asking: does jQuery still work? If it does, you can ignore Firequery. If it doesn't, you should probably change it to the `<script src="...">` option.

Comment: either bump version to correct one or provide your own key (or both)

Comment: src should be https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY, according to [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/). Did you actually omit the key or was it just being non-specific?

Comment: They say "While you can use these APIs without a key, it is very useful to have one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use following script for load jquery::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```